# How to remove "request-id" header

Tags: azure-application-insights, amplitude-analytics

Recently, I noticed my browser console is flooded with error messages like below.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.appcues.net/v1/accounts/45873/users/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/taco?url=https%3A%2F%2Fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from origin 'https://sssssssssssssss' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field request-id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I think it might be caused by the *AppInsights* libraries we added to our project recently.

I wonder if there's a way to remove the `request-id` header for `OPTIONS` request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is that you can write a custom [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0), then in the middleware, you can try to remove the `request-id` header for `OPTIONS` request.

But I'm not sure if it would have some bad impacts when removing the header. So if it's possible, you'd better adding the header in the cors rule.